# How to write each element of list in multiple text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to write each element inside a list to multiple files.

Suppose I have a list:

```
value = [ 'abc' , 'def' , 'ghi' ]
```

How can write each element inside the list `value` to multiple files? So, in this case, there should be three text files be created and each value `abc,def` and `ghi` in each file.

I have a simple python script which will write all the list values to a single text file:

```
value = ['a','b','c']

for i in value:

   f=open('/tmp/new.txt','a')
   f.write(i)
```

How can I achieve my use-case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the three text files should be called...?

Comment: @Tomalak it can be called by any name. new1, new2....newn will be better

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to write every value contained in the list to all n files, then you could just iterate through the file-writing commands, `f.write()` below, using a for loop. You're only going to write to each file once, so no need to worry about `open()`'s 'a' or 'w+' modes. Then you could print all elements of the list to each file using the `str.join()` method. I've used newline as the delimiter below, but you could choose anything.

Here's how I changed your code to do this...

```
value = ['a','b','c']
for i in range(len(value)):
    with open("new_%d.txt" % i, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(value))
```

Notice also the use of `with` to open each file. This is recommended best practice in python as it deals with clean-up of the file object that you create with `open()`. That is, you don't need to explicitly close the file after your done with `f.close()`, which can be easy to forget.

If you are set on starting with `new_1.txt` (versus `new_0.txt`, which is what will happen with the above code) then change the call to `for` to something like this:

```
for i in range(1,len(value)+1):
```

or change the call to `with` to:

```
with open("new_%d.txt" % (i+1), 'w') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for n, i in enumerate(value, 1):
    with open('/tmp/new{}.txt'.format(n), 'a') as f:
        f.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work:

```
value = ['a','b','c']

for i in range(len(value)):

   f=open('/tmp/new_%s.txt' % i ,'a')
   f.write(value[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `w+` file mode. It opens an existing file  or create if file doesn't already exist and write:

```
value = ['a','b','c']

for x in value:
   with open(f'/tmp/new{x}.txt','w+') as f:
       f.write(x)
```